# Conjugate Function Is Lower Semicontinuous

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functions, vector-spaces, semicontinuous-functions

Let $E$ be a Normed Vector Space. Let $\phi : E \rightarrow ( - \infty , + \infty] $ be a function such that $\phi$ is not equivalent to $\infty$. i.e. The set $ \{ x \in E : \phi (x) \neq \infty \}$ is not empty.

The Conjugate Function $\phi^* : E^* \rightarrow ( - \infty , + \infty]$ is defined as follows:

$$ \phi^* (f) = ^{\text{sup}} _{x \in E} \{ \{f(x) - \phi (x) \} \}$$

here, $E^*$ is the Dual Space of $E$.

My textbook claims that such $\phi^*$ is lower semicontinuous. Could someone please offer a hint for me to prove this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, given any $x$, the map $f \mapsto f(x) - \phi(x)$ is affine and continuous. In particular, the epigraph is closed and convex (in fact, weak$^*$ closed).

The epigraph of $\phi^*$ is the intersection of all these epigraphs, which makes it (weak$^*$) closed and convex. Thus $\phi^*$ is closed and (weak$^*$) lower-semicontinuous.

Comment: I don't have any experience with this idea of weak* closed or weak* lower-semicontinuous. Since these definitions haven't appeared in the textbook I am using, it should be possible to answer my question without using these things. Could you offer a different solution without these concepts please?

Comment: @DavidHughes Sure: delete all $3$ parenthetical asides in my answer. :-)

Comment: But I'm afraid that the epigraph of $\phi *$ in your example is a potentially non-finite intersection of closed sets, and therefore not necessarily closed...

Comment: @DavidHughes Actually, any arbitrary intersection (possibly infinite, or even uncountable) of closed sets is closed. Equivalently, any arbitrary union of open sets is open. This is one of the axioms of topology!

Comment: You're right! Silly mistake on my part. Thank you

Comment: @DavidHughes No problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: How might I go about showing that the epigraph of these maps is closed though? Edit: actually I can probably just use properties of the canonical injection map. Thanks